# One account, multiple ways to login?

Tags: php, database-design, architecture, oauth, openid

I want to build an application that allow users to log in via the following:

- my own authentication/authorization solution
- 3rd party providers, such as "log in with your Gmail account" or "log in with your Facebook account"

My concern is that an individual could create an account using my application's solution AND have a Gmail account AND have a FB account, etc. Though there may be various ways for a person to log in, they still all refer to the same individual. Despite multiple ways to log in, I want to be able to figure out if they refer to the same individual.

Questions:

1. Is what I am thinking even possible? (Meaning, is there some way I'll be able to figure out that a Gmail account is referring to the same person with a particular FB account?)
2. Any suggestions on general strategies on how to implement this?

Comment: Besides checking via IP or session variables, I don't think there is any way to link unrelated accounts on separate websites together.

Comment: You can always ask your users to link them: they have a place in your site where they can link a Facebook/Email account to their account and then you store that on a database

Comment: The email address on all accounts is probably common. You can probably check that when signing in, but only when the user comes from a whitelisted provider (one that you know verifies the address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the user to identify their accounts explicitly. Only let them link two accounts once they authenticate against both of them. See how stackoverflow does it (click "my logins" on your profile page).

You might also want to consider the issue of merging accounts. A user might create two accounts and then realise they only meant to have one. The way you resolve this will be specific to your problem domain and schema.

Comment: If they register with my own solution, then I have their email address. If they login with their GMail account, would I have their email address? If so, could I not use that to link the accounts? Then same with Facebook if I can get the user's email address used to register with FB (problem is that the user could potentially use a different email address for their FB account).

Comment: You've correctly identified the reason this strategy won't work in all cases. You have to support users with multiple email addresses.